# How to represent an array with mixed types

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am constructing an aggregation pipeline query with the `$substr` command from MongoDB but I don't know how to represent the array it requires in Go with the mgo driver because it contains different types of values (string, int).

Here is the query in javascript:

```
[ {$group: {"_id": {"dt": {"$substr": ["$dt",0,6]}}}} ]
```

What this is trying to do is get the substring of `dt` (from the previous stage of aggregation) with starting index 0 and ending index 6.

In Go i got:

```
[]bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"dt": bson.M{"$substr": ["$dt",0,6]}}}}}
```

but `["$dt",0,6]` is not a correct representation and everything I tried seems to fail.

Comment: If the data you get contains mixed types, it's usually better to roll out a struct for it. This gives you type safety and makes your code easier to understand for others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can represent these values using a slice of type `[]interface{}`:

```
    l := []interface{}{"$dt", 0, 6}
```

If you find the syntax a little dirty, you can easily define a local type to make it look nicer:

```
    type list []interface{}
    l := list{"$dt", 0, 6}
```