# How to write $subtract mongo query in go using mgo package?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

How to write following query in go using mgo package:

```
a:{$subtract:[variable,'$created']}
```

I tried

```
date := time.Now()
bson.M{
"a":bson.M{
    "$subtract":bson.M{date,"$created"}
}
}
```

but bson.M is a map and asks me for keys ;(

Comment: The arguments for `$subract` are an "array" of items. So just write an array as you normally would in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that array would contain `time.Time` structure and `string`, so it is mixed type array... but i think i found the answer: [How to represent an array with mixed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055037/how-to-represent-an-array-with-mixed-types)

```
type list []interface{}
date := time.Now()
sub := list{date, "$created"}
bson.M{
    "a":bson.M{
        "$subtract":sub
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to define a type: `bson.M{"a": bson.M{ "$subtract": []interface{}{date, "$created"}}}`